# Changing vertex coordinates with sliders

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to change the x and y position of the first vertex of a triangle and I want to see it updated dynamically on the screen by adjusting slider on datgui. Below is my code. Can you point me in right direction? I am really struggling on this. What is wrong when I assign variables inside animate()?

Whole code is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2WKqL/165/

I think the problem is in here.

```
function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );


params.xposv1=mesh.geometry.vertices[0].x; 
params.yposv1=mesh.geometry.vertices[0].y; 

mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a global variable `geometry`. Use its property `vertices` with index `0` in your GUI.

You can do it like that:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function addDatGui() {
  var gui = new dat.GUI();

  gui.add(geometry.vertices[0], 'x').min(-800).max(800).step(5);
  gui.add(geometry.vertices[0], 'y').min(-800).max(800).step(5);

}

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 1000;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.vertices = [
    new THREE.Vector3(-94, -200, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(92, 68, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-105, 180, 0)
  ];
  geometry.faces = [new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2)];
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffff00,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  }));
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  addDatGui();

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

  mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/97/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.3/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```